# Android NDK Error : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

all

I download Android open source (GoDroid)from http://sourceforge.net/projects/godroid
and i try to run and build it on my eclipse mar
it has NDK lib

after config everything SDK, NDK and etc.
and program can build .so file succesfully

but after i ran it on emulator the error log show
[image: error log]
and this is problem line code that show in log error
[image: line of problem]
and this C file
[image: C file]

I try to search in every same problem and try to fix it but it can't
please help , thank

Comment: Have your APK a compiled .so library? Did you include Android.mk into your project?

Comment: Yes, apk was compiled, and   i have Android.mk in my project

Comment: You'd better parse your full error stack in `text` into this question detail. So others who meet the same problem can find your question easier via search engine.